# How to convert a byte string to a number in Oracle?

Tags: string, oracle, byte

I want to convert a byte string like '1001' to the integer value 9, is there a standard function for that in Oracle ?

BTW I found a custom solution on http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no a built in function in Oracle for that, though you can use solution provided int he link in your post

Answer (score 5):

I was trying this on `Oracle` using `CONNECT BY` to convert binary to decimal in simple `SELECT` statement. Finally got the desired output using below code.

```
WITH INPUT AS
(SELECT REVERSE('&N') AS X FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(X,LEVEL,1)*POWER(2,LEVEL-1))) AS OUTPUT
FROM INPUT CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(X);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkytehexdec.html) for library from Tom Kyte for doing these type conversions.

In this case, you'd have:

```
select to_dec('1001', 2) from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for now I'll just use the information described at the Binary wiki page page.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there a standard function for that in Oracle?"

There is [BIN_TO_NUM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions013.htm#SQLRF00611) which converts a bit vector to its equivalent number.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  i VARCHAR2(100) := '1001';
  o INT;
BEGIN
  i:= TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(i, '1', '1,'),'0','0,')); 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT BIN_TO_NUM('|| i || ') FROM dual' INTO o;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i || ' => ' || o);
END;
/
```

Result:

```
1,0,0,1 => 9
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cdd7e86ea3d02c8ee9257e9043cf8c88)**